# Run boolean at start of thread causes jumping behaviour between instructions

Tags: c++, multithreading

Foo.h

```
#pragma once

#include <stdint.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <shared_mutex>
#include <atomic>

class Foo: public FooAncestor
{
private:
    std::atomic_bool start = false;

    //I do a shared mutex on the currentValue, 
    //but I took it out in order to make sure that it was not part of the problem
    mutable std::shared_mutex valueMutex;

    float currentValue = 0.0;

public: 
    Foo();
    void Start();
    inline float GetValue() { return currentValue; }
};
```

Foo.cpp

```
#include "Foo.h"

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

Foo::Foo()
{
//setting up things not related to the subject
}

void Foo::Start()
{
    std::thread updateThread( [=]()
    {
            start = true;

            while( start )
            {
                //a whole bunch of commented out code which doesn't make any difference to this

                std::this_thread::sleep_for( 200ms );

                currentTemp += 1;
            }

    } );

    updateThread.detach();
}
```

Main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello from PiCBake!\n";

    int i = 0;

    //a bunch of additional setup code here, not related to this class

    Foo foo = Foo();
    foo.Start();

    for( ;;)
    {    

    //this part is just for testing of the class and has no actual function

        std::cout << max.GetTemp() << std::endl;

        delay( 500 );

        if( ++i == 10 )
            i = 0;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever I include this, or a separate test at the beginning of the updateThread part (like:  if(!run) return;) the flow of the code does weird things. In debugging, it keeps jumping to the part where 'run' is being tested, even jumping out of the while loop when run is set in the thread, but the behavior is the same when run is set before the thread is created.

If the thread is very long it actually never gets to finish at all. Whenever I remove the variable 'run' and replace it with "true" all works as expected. If I replace the "while(run)" with "while(true)", but test 'run' right after in an if-statement, the same thing happens. 
Tried making run atomic, tried a bunch of other things, removing everything etc.

Please note that I didn't yet implemented a thread-exit condition. "run" could be set to false in the destructor or something in order to quit the thread. But that's not really the issue.

---

Update:

It must have been late, and I was probably going around in circles. It seems that changing the start value to atomic already solved it, either way, it works and I have no ^&*() clue what was going wrong...

Comment: Making `run` atomic is definitely an improvement. As is, the compiler is free to assume it never changes because doing so would cause a data race.

Comment: What compiler and compiler flags are you using?

Comment: Please provide a [repro] and add the compiler (with flags) that you are using to the question. As it is one can only speculate about the cause. Your current loop is an infinite loop, in any case.

Comment: Sounds like you are single stepping with optimizations on...

Comment: Compiler = g++, additional options are "-lstdc++fs " Optimization is off.
Also, when not stepping through but just run the code, it only runs once when I test the boolean at the start. Will edit the question to provide the minimal reproducible example as asked by uneven_mark.